# ARC ObjC code in Unity?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I include some long time used classes (written in ARC Objective-C) that are used by an iOS plugin I'm writing. I guess Unity itself does not output a project with ARC enabled by default, thus the compiler complains about missing `[super dealloc]` calls in overridden dealloc methods.

So, we can't use ARC code for our iOS plugins, or is there a way to define some classes as ARC enabled from the Unity editor?

I guess we can if we add "-fobjc-arc" to the ARC classes in "Compile sources" in Xcode.
However, that will not be feasible as it seems that Unity overwrites those settings on every export from Unity to Xcode. No one would ever add -fobjc-arc for every build. I wouldn't.

Using Unity 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select Append when you create your xcode project from unity. That way don't need to regenerate the project every time and your linker settings will not be overwritten.

Comment: The problem now is that we (and most people serious with publishing to iOS??) use a build script for iOS, which creates a new xcode project folder with every push of the "CI button". I have gone to great lengths to write scripts that put everything together, adding the right frameworks and editing the Info.plist as needed. Append doesn't really work for that?

Answer (score 0):

In Unity Editor -> Project window -> check source file -> Inspector window -> You can see 'Compile flags' label at Bottom of window. write "-fobjec-arc" at that label.

[image]

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  You say "Unity Editor" but it sounds more like you are describing Xcode.  Also `-fobjec-ard` isn't the right flag is it?

Comment: Agreed. I use Unity 4.6, and there is way to set any flags in the Inspector window after having selected a .m file. Does that work in Unity 5 perhaps?

Comment: Ok I just found a page that seems to point to that. What SnakeEyes describes seems to be a feature of Unity 5. [link](https://github.com/fan-ADN/nendSDK-Unity/wiki/Unityパッケージのインポート) The flag should be `-fobjc-arc` etc anyway.

Comment: and I attated a screenshot. maybe file extension should be '.mm'.